# Compare 2 diff dataframe having almost same values and update the old with new data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a dataframe

df1_master=

```
col_A  col_B  col_C     col_D   col_E 
 AA    abcd   1_00_11      x     y
 AB    efgh   1_11_55      x     y
 AC    abcd   2_23_55      x     y
 AD    abdf   3_00_34      x     y
```

Case2:
df1_master

```
col_A  col_B  col_C  col_D  col_E
```

dataframe with new values

```
df2_newValues =    
 A1col    A2col              
 AA       1_00_23      
 AB       1_11_24      
 AC       2_23_55     
 AD       3_00_34
 AE       4_22_33    
 AF       6_45_65
```

Expected output

```
df1_master=       
col_A  col_B  col_C     col_D   col_E 
 AA    abcd   1_00_23      x     y
 AB    efgh   1_11_24      x     y
 AC    abcd   2_23_55      x     y
 AD    abdf   3_00_34      x     y
 AE    Nan    4_22_33      Nan   Nan
 AF    Nan    6_45_65      Nan   Nan
```

I need to update the master df with new values as well as add new rows if there is any. Could you help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is by using `merge` on your `df1_master` only on col_A and col_B with `df2_newValues` after renaming the column, using `how = 'outer'` to keep all the rows possibles:

```
df2_newValues = df2_newValues.rename(columns = {'A1col':'col_A', 'A2col':'col_C'})
df_output = df1_master[['col_A', 'col_B']].merge(df2_newValues, on = 'col_A', 
                                                 how='outer')
#and fill missing value of the col_C with old value:
df_output['col_C'] = df_output['col_C'].fillna(df1_master['col_C'])
#and if you want to call it 
df1_master = df_output
```

Comment: How I can I modify above code to take care of  col_E and col_D

Comment: @Rahul you can do `df_output = df1_master[['col_A', 'col_B','col_D' ,'col_E']].merge(...)`

Comment: or if you don't know all the names: `df1_master[[col for col in df1_master.columns if col != 'col_C']]`

Comment: Hi, 
I have a situation where in df1_master has values
col_A  col_B  col_C   col_D  col_E    
                                                      
                                                      
                                                      
All the columns are blank and I want the data from df2_newValues into this empty df1_master which just have column names.

When I use merge method provided, I get blank values first and then the data,
How to get rid of the blanks

Comment: @Rahul I tried with an empty df1_master as you said and I don't get blank values first, the method works. Are you sure it's an empty DF (if you do df1_master.empty you get True) or it is empty in the sense that you have row(s) which are actually blank values (like empty string `''`)

Comment: There is one more scenario, I need to discuss.
Suppose, df1_master has data AD in col_A, and that same data is not in A1col of df2_newValues, I want ouput in such a way that in output df it shows "#AD " in col_A instead of "AD"

Comment: @Rahul before doing the line of code with `fillna(df1_master['col_C'])`, add this line: `df_output.loc[df_output['col_C'].isnull(),'col_A'] = '#' + df_output.loc[df_output['col_C'].isnull(),'col_A']`, should do the job if I understood well :)

Answer (score 1):

merge the two dataframes, pick the columns you want and rename them to match the original names.

```
df1_master = df2_newValues.merge(
      df1_master, 
      how='left', 
      left_on='A1col', 
      right_on='col_A'
).iloc[:,[0,3,1]].rename(
      {'A1col': 'col_A', 
       'A2col': 'col_C'},
axis=1)

outputs:

  col_A col_B    col_C
0    AA  abcd  1_00_23
1    AB  efgh  1_11_24
2    AC  abcd  2_23_55
3    AD  abdf  3_00_34
4    AE   NaN  4_22_33
5    AF   NaN  6_45_65
```

*update:*

to include additional columns from the first data frame, include their positional index or column name,

i.e. in the above expression, replace `iloc[:,[0,3,1]]` to `iloc[:[0,3,1,5,6]]` or `loc[:,['A1col', 'col_B', 'A2col', 'col_D','col_E']]`

```
    col_A  col_B  col_C     col_D   col_E 
0     AA    abcd   1_00_23      x     y
1     AB    efgh   1_11_24      x     y
2     AC    abcd   2_23_55      x     y
3     AD    abdf   3_00_34      x     y
4     AE    Nan    4_22_33      Nan   Nan
5     AF    Nan    6_45_65      Nan   Nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1_master, df2_newValues, left_on='col_A', 
            right_on='A1col', how='outer')
merged_df.A2col.fillna(merged_df.col_C, inplace=True)
merged_df.col_A.fillna(merged_df.A1col, inplace=True)
merged_df = merged_df.drop(['col_C','A1col'], axis=1)
merged_df.columns=['col_A','col_B','col_C']
merged_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `combine_first`

```
df1=df1.set_index('col_A')
df2.rename(columns = {'A1col':'col_A', 'A2col':'col_C'}).set_index('col_A').combine_first(df1)
Out[460]: 
      col_B    col_C
col_A               
AA     abcd  1_00_23
AB     efgh  1_11_24
AC     abcd  2_23_55
AD     abdf  3_00_34
AE      NaN  4_22_33
AF      NaN  6_45_65
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting all the old values in col_C and col_A is displayed Blank